# can't get custum control to call anther custom control properrly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple Custom control called sLabel.ascx.  Inside this control I only have:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label" />
```

Inside the code behind I have:

```
 public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return Label.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            Label.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

This custom control is being used in another custom control called pic.ascx:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Label" src="~/Controls/sLabel.ascx"%>
<uc:Label runat="server" ID="lblFirstName" Text="First name:" />
<uc:Label runat="server" ID="lblActualFirstName" />
```

In the code behind I have:

```
public string ActualFirstNameText 
    {
        get
        {
            return lblActualFirstName.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            lblActualFirstName.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

In my default.aspx I have:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="pic" src="~/Controls/pic.ascx"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc:pic runat="server" id="pic1" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In my code behind I have:

```
pic p = (pic)Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/pic.ascx");
p.ActualFirstNameText = "Something";
```

When I run this I see only "First Name: " and not "First Name: Something"

What am I doing wrong.  I thought calling ActualFirstNameText would do it.

Thanks

Comment: I think what you mean to have is `pic1.ActualFirstNameText = "Something";`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked, forgot they had ID's also.  I also thought you had to load the controls.....

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use:

```
pic1.ActualFirstNameText = "Something";
```

No need to use `LoadControl` at all. That's useful if you are dynamically adding user controls. But since you aren't, it isn't needed.